# Error mounting ebs in amazon ec2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, mount, sudo

I have accidently changed permissions for my `/etc/sudoers` and `/etc` folders and thereby I am unable to access anything through `sudo`.

After that I detached my ebs volume from the instance and attached it to another instance by using device name `/dev/sdf`. But when I am mounting it to new instance by using

```
sudo mkdir -m 000 /vol-a
sudo mount /dev/sdf /vol-a
```

it returns an error saying

```
 mount:/dev/xvdf is write protected,mounting read only mount:wrong fs type,bad option
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running **fdisk -l** just to make sure /def/sdf is the actual block name, so probably it should mount with:

> sudo mount /dev/sdf1 /vol-a

Comment: The better tool to use is `blkid`. less noise, plus it shows you filesystem types & labels.

Comment: yeah thanx for your help it worked great yar....